# php simple xml how to read multiple nodes with different child node levels

Tags: php, xml, arrays, foreach, nodes

I have an xml file that has different named nodes and multi level child nodes (that are different between each node.) How should I access the data? Will it require many nested for loops?

Here is a sample of the xml code:

```
       <start_info>
          <info tabindex="1">
                  <infonumber>1</infonumber>
                  <trees>green</trees>
           </info>
       </start_info>

          <people>
                <pe>
                    <people_ages>
                       <range number="1">
                          <age value="1">1</age>
                          <age value="2">2</age>
                        </range>
                    </people_ages>
                </pe>
          </people>
```

Here is my code so far:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");

echo $xml->getName() . "start_info";

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
  {
  echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br />";
  }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Extract all people?

Comment: yes and display it on the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some example code that I hope can point you in the right direction. Essentially, it is *walking the [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)* echoing the element name and values. Note that the whitespace between the elements is significant, so for the purposes of the demo, the XML is compacted. You may find a similar issue loading from a file, so if you are not getting the expected output you might need to strip whitespace nodes.

You could replace the `//root/*` with a different [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) for example `//people` if you only wanted the `<people>` elements.

```
<?php
    $xml = <<<XML
    <root><start_info><info tabindex="1"><infonumber>1</infonumber><trees>green</trees></info></start_info>
    <people><pe><people_ages><range number="1"><age value="1">1</age><age value="2">2</age></range></people_ages></pe></people>
    </root>
    XML;

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->recover = true;
    $dom->loadXML($xml);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $nodelist = $xpath->query('//root/*');
    foreach ($nodelist as $node) {
        echo "\n$node->tagName";
        getData($node);
    }

    function getData($node) {
        foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {

            if ($child->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
                echo ($child->tagName === '' ? '' : "\n").$child->tagName;
            }

            if ($child->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE) {
                echo '->'.$child->nodeValue;
            }

            if ($child->hasChildNodes()) {
                getData($child); // recursive call
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
$xml_file = 'file.xml';
$xmlobj = simplexml_load_file($xml_file);
echo $xmlobj->getName() . 'start_info<br />';
foreach($xmlobj->children() as $childs) {
  echo $childs->getName(). ': '. '<br />';
  if($childs->count()>1) {
    foreach($childs as $child) {
     echo $child->getName(). ': '. $child. '<br />';
    }
  }
}
```