# PHP - XPATH request on XML file - childrens and siblings

Tags: php, xml, xpath, siblings, descendant

i have following XML document from which i need to get for each node  his childrens ( < KA>/< kod> and < TPV>/< TPV>/...< A> ). For better understanding, here is what i need:

```
<KATU/KA/kod> | <KATU/TPV/TPVS/TN> | <KATU/TPV/TPVS/TSA/TS/A>
k11 | VP11 | 11
k21 | VP21 | 21
k31 | VP31 | 31
k32 | VP32 | 32
k33 | VP33 | 33
k41 | VP41 | 41
k41 | VP41 | 42
k41 | VP41 | 43
k51 | VP51 | 51
```

The main problem (eg. values from example k41 and his 41,42,43) is that nodes which i need to get are not childrens but siblings in order < KA>< TPV>< KA>< TPV>...

So I need to find all < A> nodes (children of < TPV>< TPVS>< TSA>< TS>) and then get its top sibling (mean his parents < TPV> top sibling is < KA>) to get < KA>/< kod>

I hope you understend my problem, Im not able to describe it more, cos of my english.

Thanks for reply

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<PV>
    <PRAV_VZTAHY>
        <TYPPRA>
            <TN>VP</TN> 
        </TYPPRA>
    </PRAV_VZTAHY>
    <OPRAV_SUBJEKT>
        <CHAROS_KOD>1112</CHAROS_KOD> 
        <OPSUB_ADRESA>
            <adresa>
                <nazev_ulice>xxx</nazev_ulice> 
            </adresa>
        </OPSUB_ADRESA>
    </OPRAV_SUBJEKT>
    <OKRESY>
        <OKRES>
            <nuts4>123456</nuts4> 
            <name>asdf</name> 
        </OKRES>
        <OBCE>
            <OBEC>
                <kod>594580</kod> 
                <name>mn</name> 
            </OBEC>
            <KATU>
                <KA>
                    <kod>k11</kod> 
                    <name>q11</name> 
                </KA>
                <TPV>
                    <TPVS>
                        <TN>VP11</TN> 
                        <TSA>
                            <TS>
                                <A>11</A> 
                            </TS>
                        </TSA>
                    </TPVS>
                </TPV>
            </KATU>
        </OBCE>
        <OKRES>
            <nuts4>46786</nuts4> 
            <name>qwer</name> 
        </OKRES>
        <OBCE>
            <OBEC>
                <kod>525804</kod> 
                <name>mn</name> 
            </OBEC>
            <KATU>
                <KA>
                    <kod>k21</kod> 
                    <name>q21</name> 
                </KA>
                <TPV>
                    <TPVS>
                        <TN>VP21</TN> 
                        <TSA>
                            <TS>
                                <A>21</A> 
                            </TS>
                        </TSA>
                    </TPVS>
                </TPV>
            </KATU>
            <OBEC>
                <kod>540978</kod> 
                <name>mn</name> 
            </OBEC>
            <KATU>
                <KA>
                    <kod>k31</kod> 
                    <name>q31</name> 
                </KA>
                <TPV>
                    <TPVS>
                        <TN>VP31</TN> 
                        <TSA>
                            <TS>
                                <A>31</A> 
                            </TS>
                        </TSA>
                    </TPVS>
                </TPV>
                <KA>
                    <kod>k32</kod> 
                    <name>q32</name> 
                </KA>
                <TPV>
                    <TPVS>
                        <TN>VP32</TN> 
                        <TSA>
                            <TS>
                                <A>32</A>
                            </TS>
                        </TSA>
                    </TPVS>
                </TPV>
                <KA>
                    <kod>k33</kod> 
                    <name>q33</name> 
                </KA>
                <TPV>
                    <TPVS>
                        <TN>VP33</TN> 
                        <TSA>
                            <TS>
                                <A>33</A>  
                            </TS>
                        </TSA>
                    </TPVS>
                </TPV>
            </KATU>
            <OBEC>
                <kod>541265</kod> 
                <name>mn</name> 
            </OBEC>
            <KATU>
                <KA>
                    <kod>k41</kod> 
                    <name>q41</name> 
                </KA>
                <TPV>
                    <TPVS>
                        <TN>VP41</TN> 
                        <TSA>
                            <TS>
                                <A>41</A> 
                            </TS>
                            <TS>
                                <A>42</A>  
                            </TS>
                            <TS>
                                <A>43</A> 
                            </TS>
                        </TSA>
                    </TPVS>
                </TPV>
            </KATU>
            <OBEC>
                <kod>553387</kod> 
                <name>mn</name> 
            </OBEC>
            <KATU>
                <KA>
                    <kod>k51</kod> 
                    <name>q51</name> 
                </KA>
                <TPV>
                    <TPVS>
                        <TN>VP51</TN> 
                        <TSA>
                            <TS>
                                <A>51</A> 
                            </TS>
                        </TSA>
                    </TPVS>
                </TPV>
            </KATU>
        </OBCE>
    </OKRESY>
</PV>
```

here is my start:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath("//KATU") as $ku) {
        print_r($ku);
        print "<hr />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read each node and check if that node has a child node or not. And then loop through them. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611702/php-simple-xml-how-to-read-multiple-nodes-with-different-child-node-levels) is a link to stackoverflow question which I think will answer your question.

Or you can also check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) link. Check the comments of people in them.

I hope you will find answer from these links.

Comment: Currently, your answer is not much more than a collection of links. If other questions on Stackoverflow already have an answer for this problem, please do not answer here, because then the question should be closed as a duplicate. If there is no duplicate post, extend this answer to include all necessary information to solve the problem.